# Javascript - Return a JSON-object from JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to solve a task here. I need to return a JSON-object to my function LearnObject - as I have understood it is an array right now. Do I have to use the JSON.stringify method to solve this? Can anybody help please?

Thank you!

```js
var answer = "No"
var mood = "I'm tired";

var answer = "No today"
var mood = "Not cool at all";

var answer = "maybe"
var mood = "just tired";

var answer = "yes";
var mood = "i'm ready for it";


console.log(LearnObject(answer, mood));

function LearnObject(reason,mood) {
    var obj =[];
    var notValidAnswer = 'Try again';
    var shortReason = ' Please explain your feelings in more details';

    switch(answer){
        case 'yes':
        obj.push ('Nice');
        break;
        case 'no': 
        obj.push ('not at all');
        break;
        case 'maybe':
        obj.push ('be nicer');
        break;
        default:
        obj.push(notValidAnswer);
    }
if(validate(reason) && obj.indexOf(notValidAnswer)==-1){
obj.push(shortReason);
}
var objLength = obj.length;
 for (var i = 0; i<objLength; i++) {
 obj.push("Enjoy your day");
}
return obj;

}

function validate(reason){
    return reason.split('').length < 3
}
```

Comment: "I need to return a JSON-object" — [There is no such thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Maybe you need to return a JavaScript object. Maybe you need to return a string representation of a JSON text. It isn't clear from your question, and I can't imply it from your code.

Comment: I don't really understand what the code is supposed to do, but returning an Object instead of an Array goes like this: `var obj = {};` then something like `obj.answer = "be nicer";` and finally `return obj;`

Comment: @ChrisG — Arrays are a type of object though, so ‍♂️

Comment: Hey @Quentin thanks sorry I am new in this coding world #rookie . The question goes more as how can I make LearnObject() return a JSON-object - I hope that clarify’s the confusion and my question

Comment: @Quentin I know. Does this information help here in any way? No. So ‍♂️ indeed

Comment: @NeilO — I'd already figured our you meant from and not to, but I still have no idea what you are trying to do. It *sounds* like you don't understand the task you've been given, but we can't tell you what whoever gave it to you was thinking.

Comment: Hey @Quentin and guys thanks sorry I am new in this coding world #rookie . The question goes more as how can I make LearnObject() return a JSON-object - I hope that clarify’s the confusion and my question

Comment: @NeilO — As I said in my first comment, there is no such thing as a JSON object. So you can't. (And Stackoverflow doesn't support hashtags so please don't litter comments with them).

Comment: Hey guys I just want my function or my array to become in a json format :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSON.parse
sample code is:
     var obj = JSON.parse('{"var1":"Hello", "var2":"hii!"}');

```
        document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML  
                = obj.var1 + " " + obj.var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

it was hard to understand what do you want, but i think this can help you

```js
var answer1 = "no"
var mood1 = "I'm tired";

var answer2 = "No today"
var mood2 = "Not cool at all";

var answer3 = "maybe"
var mood3 = "just tired";

var answer4 = "yes";
var mood4 = "i'm ready for it";


console.log(LearnObject(answer1, mood1));

function LearnObject(reason,mood) {
    var obj = {};
    var notValidAnswer = 'Try again';
    var shortReason = ' Please explain your feelings in more details';

    switch(reason){
        case 'yes':
        obj['somefield'] = 'Nice';
        break;
        case 'no': 
        obj['somefield'] = 'not at all';
        break;
        case 'maybe':
        obj['somefield'] = 'be nicer';
        break;
        default:
        obj['somefield'] = notValidAnswer;
    }
if(validate(reason) && obj.somefield != notValidAnswer){
  obj['someOtherField'] = shortReason;
}
obj['anotherOneField'] = "Enjoy your day"

return obj;

}

function validate(reason){
    return reason.split('').length < 3
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try JSON.stringify()? That sounds like what you need.

A great way to learn how to do things like this is to set up a sandbox somewhere and try it. This site provides such a sandbox and even has an example of stringifying an array...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

A couple side notes on your code...

- Use "let" or "const" instead of "var"
- Use "===" instead of "==" for equality checks
- Looks like you may also have a bug on your switch statement with the variable "answer"